# Text with two columns (different from multicols)

Tags: indentation

How to write the following text (see the below image) where every line contains two parts. I want the right part of each line to be in the same (horizontal) level. How can I achieve this?

[image]

Comment: You could use a table or a multi-column feature of LaTeX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to achieve what you want is to create a tabular.

```
\begin{tabular}{p{4cm} p{4cm}}
text: & text: \\
text: & text: \\
text: & text: 
\end{tabular}
```

[image]